# Configuring 'redis-sentinel' gem with 'sidekiq'

Tags: ruby, redis, sidekiq

Need help configuring '**redis-sentinel**' gem with '**sidekiq**'.

Getting this error -> Error fetching message: ERR unknown command 'sentinel'

Please see this gist (Start from the bottom) - https://gist.github.com/nitinstp23/6919253

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one missing step. You need to define `Redis.current` like so:

```
redis_connection = proc {
  Redis.current = Redis.new(master_name: "mymaster", sentinels: sentinels[Rails.env])
}
redis = ConnectionPool.new(size: 10, &redis_connection)
```

Comment: What happens if one of the sentinels are down, and I attempt to write to it? Will it automatically try another?

Comment: @HenleyChiu yes - this is exactly the idea behind the sentinels. You should have at least three sentinels out of this reason